# ImportError using Seleniumwire

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, seleniumwire

I can't figure out what is causing the error.
Python 3.9, 3.10.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\S\SS\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from seleniumwire import webdriver
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\seleniumwire\webdriver.py", line 14, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver import TouchActions  # noqa
ImportError: cannot import name 'TouchActions' from 'selenium.webdriver' (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\__init__.py)
```

Code:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
```

Comment: I think you need selenium.interactions, not selenium.webdriver

Comment: @pcalkins, no, i need exactly `seleniumwire.webdriver`.

Answer (score 2):

To use [**Selenium Wire**](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire#selenium-wire) first you have to install [*selenium-wire*](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/) as follows;

```
pip install selenium-wire
```

> Note: If you get an error about not being able to build cryptography you may be running an old version of pip. You need to try upgrading pip with `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` and then re-run the above mentioned command.

Now you can proceed with the import as:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
```

Comment: Of course I downloaded selenium-wire.

Answer (score 2):

Its a bug:
[GitHub issue](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10395)

Just need to download selenium 4.1.0 with:

```
pip install selenium==4.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

try that

```
pip install setuptools
```